# Is there a way to upload folders instead of files to Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I was wondering if there was a way to upload entire folders instead of files when using browsers on Ubuntu One? This would be really useful.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible. Using the Ubuntu One client, you'll just add the folder and it'll be kept in sync, though.

Comment: Well, I am quite sad to read that, but thank you anyway for your help.
Have a nice day!